# WARN/InputManagerService(59): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@44f8eb98

Tags: android, facebook

i am getting this problem while eshtablishing facebook android sdk connection..
when i m running the code i getting this error message on the logcat:

```
 WARN/InputManagerService(59): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@44f8eb98
```

this is my code i have already refrenced facebook android sdk to my project:

```
package com.conn;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.facebook.android.*;
import com.facebook.android.Facebook.*;

 public class MyGreatActivity extends Activity {

Facebook facebook = new Facebook("YOUR_APP_ID");

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    facebook.authorize(this, new String[] { "email", "read_stream" },
 new DialogListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {}

        @Override
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {}

        @Override
        public void onError(DialogError e) {}

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {}
    });
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}


 }
```

Please help

Comment: Mine fixed by: Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes this warning appears in the log for no good reason and you can just ignore it (see also [this bugreport](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17564)).

However, if you have problems and your code doesn't function properly you should check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6042871/warningwindow-already-focused-ignoring-focus-gain-starting-facebook-app-from-e) or [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3140524/geting-window-already-focused-ignoring-focus-gain-of-com-android-internal-view) for a solution

Comment: i have facebook android sdk referenced to my project