# window already focused - ignoring focus gain of com.android.internal.view

Tags: android, android-intent

I have seen many solutions to this but none works for me! I faced this problem in two previous occasions and I just had to revert to my backup code for it to work. I never found out why this happens. Some people say its just a warning, so you can ignore it. But I am not able to switch from one intent to another. This is the exact case - I have made a menu from where I add something. So when I click on menu, and then click add item, It doesn't do anything! Just gives this warning and stays on the same screen. So, i am stuck!
Can anyone please explain why this error is caused and what is the best way to eliminate it?

```
WARN/InputManagerService(61): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@405b1d68
```

Comment: `"But I am not able to switch from one intent to another."` Would you please care to elaborate?

Comment: edited the post. I hope its clear now!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6042871/warningwindow-already-focused-ignoring-focus-gain-starting-facebook-app-from    check this.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add your activity into Manifest file :

```
<activity android:name="activity name" android:screenOrientation="portrait" ></activity>
```

Answer (score 2):

Check your event handler method for the menu.  I found that I was using

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
```

I switched to the following and fixed the problem.

```
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item)
```

I was getting the same warning message and my event was not firing the next activity.  Look at your method and see if it indicates that you are overriding it.  I was not.  Once I changed the method I was overriding and worked.