# window already focused - ignoring focus gain of xxx.xxx.xxx

Tags: android, android-activity, notifications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [window already focused - ignoring focus gain of com.android.internal.view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6980693/window-already-focused-ignoring-focus-gain-of-com-android-internal-view)

I use Notification to notify user if he/she has a site-message, when user click the noticication it will focus to MessageActivity to show the message.

It works fine except one case: If the the current focused Activity is MessageActivity when user click the new Notification the Console will print **Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy** and nothing happend.

Please help me. *The MessageActivity's launchmode is singleTask.*

```
    Notification notification = new Notification();  
    notification.icon = R.drawable.msg;  
    notification.tickerText = content
    notification.defaults=Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;  
    notification.audioStreamType= android.media.AudioManager.ADJUST_LOWER;  
    notification.when=System.currentTimeMillis();

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MessageActivity.class); 
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    notificationIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);  
    notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);  
    notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);  
    notificationIntent.setAction(System.currentTimeMillis());
    notificationIntent.putExtra("msgid", msgid); 

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(AutoActivity.this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);  
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(MainActivity.this, "get a message", "test", pendingIntent);  
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL; 
    manager.notify(msgid, notification);
```

Comment: I'm confused, what is the problem? It seems like if the window is already focused you have achieved what you want

Comment: When focus on MessageActivity it will get data from intent to show the message but in my case nothing happend. I debug that get data from intent in onResume() and the data still the original one after window is already focused printed in logcat